# Data Type Validation in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed, complex-data-types

I need to validate the file with respect to the data types. I have a file with below data,

data.csv

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
100  | XYZ  | 200  | 2020-07-11
200  | XYZ  | 500  | 2020-07-10
300  | XYZ  | 700  | 2020-07-09
```

I have another file having the configurations,

Config_file.txt

```
Columns   = Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
Data_type = numeric|string|numeric|date
Delimiter = |
```

I have to compare the configuration file and data file and return a result. 
For example:
In configuration file data_type of Col1 is numeric. In case if i get any string value in Col1 in data file, the script should return `Datatype Mismatch Found in Col1`. I have tried with `awk`, if its one line item its easy to get it done by defining the position of the columns. But am not sure how to loop entire file column by column ad check the data.

I have also tried providing the patterns and achieve this. But am unable to validate complete file. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
awk -F "|" '$1 ~ "^[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$" && $4 ~ "^[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$" && length($5) == 10 {print}' data.csv
```

The goal is to compare the data file (data.csv) and Data_Type in config file(Config_file.txt) for each column and check if any column is having datatype mismatch.

For example, consider below data

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
100  | XYZ  | 200  | 2020-07-11
ABC  | XYZ  | 500  | 2020-07-10  -- This is incorrect data because Col1 is having string value `ABC`, in config file, the data type is numeric
300  | XYZ  | 700  | 2020-07-09
300  | XYZ  | 700  | 2020-07-09
300  | XYZ  | XYZ  | 2020-07-09 -- Incorrect Data
300  | 300  | 700  | 2020-07-09
300  | XYZ  | 700  | XYX        -- Incorrect Data
```

The data type provided in config table is as below,

```
Columns   = Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
Data_type = numeric|string|numeric|date
```

The script should echo the result as `Data Type Mismatch Found in Col1`

Comment: Could you please post more clear sample expected output in your question and let us know, which will give us more clarity on this question, thank you.

Comment: Added additional example as well. Let me know it its helpful

Comment: How strictly do you have to validate the date? You can obviously compare with a simple regexp like `[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}` but that would allow a "date" like `1234-56-78` - is that OK or do you need to check that what's in that field is an actual data and disallow things like `2020-02-30`, etc.?

Comment: Validating with the pattern is fine having `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a skeleton solution in GNU awk. In lack of sample output I improvised:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=" *= *"
}
function numeric(p) {                # testing for numeric
    if(p==(p+0))
        return 1
    else return 0
}
function string(p) {                 # cant really fail string test, right
    return 1
}
function date(p) {
    gsub(/-/," ",p)
    if(mktime(p " 0 0 0")>=0)
        return 1
    else return 0
}
NR==FNR{                             # process config file
    switch($1) {
        case "Columns":
            a["Columns"]=$NF;
            break
        case "Data_type":
            a["Data_type"]=$NF;
            break
        case "Delimiter":
            a["Delimiter"]=$NF;
    }
    if(a["Columns"] && a["Data_type"] &&  a["Delimiter"]) {
        split(a["Columns"],c,a["Delimiter"])
        split(a["Data_type"],d,a["Delimiter"])
        for(i in c) {                # b["Col1"]="string" etc.
            b[c[i]]=d[i]
            FS= a["Delimiter"]
        }
    }
    next
}
FNR==1{                              # processing headers of data file
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        h[i]=$i                      # h[1]="Col1" etc.
    }
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {              # process all fields
        f=b[h[i]]                     # using indirect function calls check
        printf "%s%s",(@f($i)?$i:"FAIL"),(i==NF?ORS:FS)  # the data
    }
}' config <(tr -d \  <data)  # deleting space from your data as "|"!="  |  "
```

Sample output:

```
FAIL|Col2|FAIL|FAIL
100|XYZ|200|2020-07-11
200|XYZ|500|2020-07-10
300|XYZ|700|2020-07-09
FAIL|XYZ|FAIL|FAIL           # duplicated previous record and malformed it
```

Comment: Gotta run, coming back later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^=]+=[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    cfg_tag2val[tag] = val
    next
}

FNR == 1 {
    FS = cfg_tag2val["Delimiter"]
    $0 = $0
    reqd_NF = split(cfg_tag2val["Columns"],reqd_names)
    split(cfg_tag2val["Data_type"],reqd_types)
}

NF != reqd_NF {
    printf "%s: Error: line %d NF (%d) != required NF (%d)\n", FILENAME, FNR, NF, reqd_NF | "cat>&2"
    got_errors = 1
}

FNR == 1 {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        reqd_name = reqd_names[i]
        name = $i
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",name)
        if ( name != reqd_name ) {
            printf "%s: Error: line %d col %d name (%s) != required col name (%s)\n", FILENAME, FNR, i, name, reqd_name | "cat>&2"
            got_errors = 1
        }
    }
}

FNR > 1 {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        reqd_type = reqd_types[i]
        if ( reqd_type != "string" ) {
            value = $i
            gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",value)
            type = val2type(value)
            if ( type != reqd_type ) {
                printf "%s: Error: line %d field %d (%s) type (%s) != required field type (%s)\n", FILENAME, FNR, i, value, type, reqd_type | "cat>&2"
                got_errors = 1
            }
        }
    }
}

END { exit got_errors }

function val2type(val,  type) {
    if      ( val == val+0 )                     { type = "numeric" }
    else if ( val ~ /^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}$/ ) { type = "date" }
    else                                         { type = "string" }
    return type
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk config.txt data.csv
data.csv: Error: line 3 field 1 (ABC) type (string) != required field type (numeric)
data.csv: Error: line 6 field 3 (XYZ) type (string) != required field type (numeric)
data.csv: Error: line 8 field 4 (XYX) type (string) != required field type (date)
```

Comment: Note that I assumed "string" to mean "neither date nor numeric" - if that's not what it's supposed to mean in your data then it's an easy tweak but update your question to clarify your requirements.